# Area of a cuboid's shadow/projection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solid-geometry

Given a cuboid with lengths $L_{x}$, $L_{y}$, and $L_{z}$ (where $L_{x}$ is the length along the $x$ axis for a non-rotated cuboid), what would be the area of its projection on the $YZ$ plane if rotated about the $y$ and $z$ axes?

I have worked out that area for a rotation on just the $z$ axis is calculated by $L_{z}(L_{y}\cos\theta_{z}+L_{x}\sin\theta_{z})$, but the shape isn't a rectangle once both axes have a rotation.

Comment: This problem is a generalization of this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2725780/orthogonal-projection-area-of-a-3-d-cube)